# How to unlock/login my app using smart lock

Tags: android, face-recognition

Hello there I am new to this kind a work. Actually I want to add a lock before my app like Face Recognition in modern Android Devices with Android 8.0 Oreo!

I have successfully added Biometric Unlock/Finger Print Scanner in my app and can allow user to scan and login into the app. Now what I want to use Android Natively Provided Face Unlock Intent to login into my own app!

I just want to invoke the face recognition activity of my Android 8.0 Oreo Device if available and detect the user face recognize it and allow him to be logged in on success of face recognition!

Can somebody please tell me how can done this, I know I can do this using openCV or any other third party libs! But I need to do this with minimum code and with existing Android Native Face Recognition Activity Intent.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but at this time it's not supported.

> Android 9 only includes fingerprint integration for BiometricPrompt.

It will be supported at some point, though. You can read more about it [here](https://source.android.com/security/biometric)

Comment: I interpret the documentation as saying _"Android 9 **from the AOSP tree** only includes fingerprint integration for BiometricPrompt."_, i.e. a device manufacturer could integrate additional modalities themselves if they wanted to. There'd be no way for an app developer to pick a specific modality though, at least not the way the API looks like right now.

Comment: @Michael that is what it says, yes. However, without the API supporting it globally and no specific device mentioned it is not possible to point the OP to device specific docs. Additionally, the UX would be questionable considering you can't choose which one to use regardless of whether the device supports it.

Comment: The user can choose, sort of. The page you linked to states that _"If your device supports multiple biometrics, you can specify a default. However, you must allow users to change their preferred biometric in Settings"_. App developers can't choose, though (not until Google adds that to the API anyway).

Comment: @Michael agreed. The app developer can not. I am looking forward to the API getting the "face" lift it needs. Pun intended!

Comment: @kandroidj - so it is not possible to do Face Unlock like Fingerprint Unlock Right?